# Coded UI Test Builder not identifying DevExpress Grid Control in WPF Test Automation project

Tags: wpf, automated-tests, coded-ui-tests, ranorex, devexpress-wpf

In our WPF Test Automation project, Coded UI Test Builder is not identifying DevExpress Grid Control with UIMap. But CUIT is just able to identify the cells or ItemTemplate within the GridControl but not the whole DevExpress GridControl.

Can someone help on how to get identify the DevExpress GridControl with Coded UI (CUIT) or Ranorex?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to enable the setting "Show all Elements" in the Plugins settings in Ranorex Studio. A lot more elements will be shown if this setting is set to True.
Just open the Global Settings dialog in Ranorex Studio navigate to the Plugins tab and scroll to the WPF section.

Comment: By default `Show all Elements` setting is in true in Ranorex studio. Still no help with my above issue.

Comment: Can someone please answer